# Issues with Ballerina Integrator

Tags: visual-studio-code, ballerina, ballerina-vscode-plugin, wso2-bi

I have tried the FTP samples of Ballerina Integrator with 1.0.3,1.0.5 and 1.1.0 too. I am facing the same issues with all those mentioned versions. But i am able to run Ballerina Samples with the help of Ballerina Versions 1.0.3, 1.0.5 and 1.1.0 When am facing issues means while running the samples of Ballerina Integrator alone. Through Command Prompt and Also VSCode Editor Same issues only coming.

I dont know where am doing the mistake and which mistake am doing?

Please help me to do further.

For the reference, please find the screenshots

[image: Command Prompt Console]

[image: VSCode Console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install Ballerina Integrator alone which is packed with Ballerina 1.0.2 so no need to install Ballerina again or separately.

Locally installed "Ballerina Integrator with Ballerina" is lower version ie)1.0.2, In VSCode "Ballerina Integrator with Ballerina" is latest one ie)1.1.0.

Mismatched version is the main problem which i was faced.

I have removed BI and Ballerina plugin from VSCode just tried the samples from random location now its working fine

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have installed Ballerina again after installing Ballerina Integrator. You do not have to install Ballerina again if you have already installed Ballerina Integrator. You can download the latest Ballerina Integrator from [here](https://wso2.com/integration/ballerina-integrator/).

Execute command `which ballerina` and make sure the path is similar to `<EI_HOME>/ballerina-integrator/bin/ballerina`.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah i have checked from EI_Home ballerina version is 1.0.2, Globally installed ballerina is jBallerina 1.1.0 What should i do now? Please guide me

Answer (score 1):

You can install Ballerina 1.0.2 using `ballerina dist` command as well. Use `ballerina dist pull jballerina-1.0.2` to downgrade the ballerina version.